Is anyone else experiencing wide problems with window layering/focus on Sonoma 14.4.1?
I'm not sure how exactly to describe this. Windows that obscure the actually active window. Focus not being where it should. Seems especially to hit Electron apps although I observe it regularly with Calendar.app as well. It seems to have hit in a recent OS Update. I think at least 14.3 or 14.4.
I'm mostly curious if this is a known issue or not. I see it widely reported at my employer so that's reach of several thousand.
As one example, here's a heavily obfuscated screenshot where Slack is at the top of the window stack but Chrome actually has the focus and is shown that way in the menu bar.

Some more examples:
Monosnap with active focus but Messenger.app at top of window focus:

Chrome with active focus but Messenger.app at top of window focus:


I think we need more information about the problem. Screenshots would help. You can bet that if there were a widespread problem, it would be reported on sites like MacRumors. If it's happening on large numbers of computers at one employer, then it could be a particular software setup.

@benwiggy Sorry hadn't seen your comment since I posted. I just added an example image. Hope that helps.
